# java and javascript - Access to a Map

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am using rhino to execute a javascript code in my Java program.
I can't iterate the map in the javascript.

### Java side:

```
private final Map<Long, ClassEmployees > employees ;
...
employees.put (numEmployees, new ClassEmployees());
...
```

### JavaScript side:

```
keys = employees.keySet();
for (var i in keys) {
  print ("++ " + i);   // ===> print the method ??? Strange...no?
}
```

### ===> Output :

> ++ getClass 
>   ++ iterator 
>   ++ toArray 
>   ++ addAll 
>  
>   ++ remove 
>   ++ equals 
>   ++ containsAll 
>   ++ class 
>   ++ hashCode 
>   ++ contains 
>   ++ wait 
>   ++ add 
>   ++ size
>   
>   ++ clear 
>   ++ isEmpty 
>   ++ notify 
>   ++ empty 
>  
>   ++ retainAll 
>   ++ toString 
>   ++ notifyAll 
>   ++ removeAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `keys` variable holds a reference to a Java `Set` object,
but the JavaScript's `for in` construct does not really know how to iterate over it, and thus treats it just like any other object.

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object

The `Set` object methods are enumerable properties of it, hence that is what you get.

To iterate over the underlying values of your `Set`, you should use an explicit iterator (just like in Java), or simply convert it to an array, like that:

```
for each (var i in keys.toArray() ) {
     //...        
}
```